# Reprojection matrix Q from Projection matrices P_left and P_right

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

The reprojection matrix Q (4 x 4) and a disparity value (i.e pixel shift) are typically needed to generate a point cloud from coplanar stereo image pairs,
[as such.](http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html) Coplanar planes allow for disparity search on the same epipolar line.
How can matrix Q be obtained or what is an alternative route to 3D reconstruction if the individual projection matrices P (4 x 3) are given ?

Comment: Have you found any solution or this?

Comment: Just a hint: [OReilly - "Learning Opencv" - page 451]

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

The `Q` or reprojection matrix can be compiled if you have the `P` or projection matrices. Lets say `Pl` and `Pr` are your left and right projection matrices respectively...

```
Pl = 
[F 0 Cxl 0]
[0 F Cyl 0]
[0 0  1  0]

Pr = 
[F 0 Cxr F.Tx]
[0 F Cyr  0  ]
[0 0  1   0  ]
```

Then your `Q` matrix is as follows, just substitute in the corresponding elements of the `P` matrices...

```
Q = 
[1 0   0       -Cxl     ]
[0 1   0       -Cyl     ]
[0 0   0         F      ]
[0 0 -1/Tx  (Cxl-Cxr)/Tx]

Q =
[1 0        0                      -Pl(0,2)             ]
[0 1        0                      -Pl(1,2)             ]
[0 0        0                      Pl(0,0)              ]
[0 0 -Pr(0,0)/Pr(0,3)  (Pl(0,2)-Pr(0,2))*Pr(0,0)/Pr(0,3)]
```

In most modern cameras `Q(3,3)` is going to be 0.

Hope this helps

Comment: Very informative answer!  Can you also please cite  a book/paper reference where you read this? Again, very informative.

Comment: Also, for identical right and left cameras, the value (Cxl - Cxr) has to be zero. right?

Comment: Yes, Cxl-Cxr will likely be 0 in modern cameras, as I mentioned above. "Learning OpenCV 3" has some good references to the math involved in its functions.